# Templated data type that might have an array of length zero

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, types

I want to have a data type, which has a certain templated amount of extra information, but the extra information might be non-existent.

My first idea was just doing this:

```
template <size_t SIZE>
class Data
{
    int a;
    int bs[SIZE];

public:
    Data(int a, int bs[SIZE]) : a(a),  bs(bs) {};
};
```

But after reading some other questions about zero-sized arrays here, this seems to result in troubles if I instantiate the template with `SIZE = 0`, in this case my compiler will give my an `<error-type>` if I try to call the constructor with `Data<0> d(1, {});`

One obvious solution would be to create an extra type for this case:

```
class DataZero
{
    int a;

public:
    Data(int a) : a(a) {};
};
```

but I would immensely prefer a solution, which would allow me to keep the templates everywhere and allow me to write `Data<0>` if that is possible. Also, maybe I am just instantiating `Data<0>` wrong, but any input on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `allow me to write Data<0>` - which would do what?

Comment: not having to introduce a new type `DataZero` if it is possible to template that one out.

Comment: `std::array<int, SIZE> bs;` ?

Comment: `Data(int a, int bs[SIZE]) : a(a),  bs(bs) {}` is invalid, c-array is not copyable, (and `int bs[SIZE]` is actually `int* bs`, you might want `Data(int a, int (&bs)[SIZE])` instead (and use `std::copy` for initialization)).

Comment: Would `std::array` copy correctly using my syntax if I'd use the solution you suggested below?

Comment: `std::array` can be copied (using your syntax). You can still specialize case when `size == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using template specialization.

```
template <>
class Data<0>
{
    int a;

  public:
    Data(int a) : a(a) {}
};
```

However, when creating an object of type `Data<0>`, you'll have to use

```
Data<0> d(1);
```

If you must support use of

```
Data<0> d(1, {});
```

you can use a place holder argument that is ignored.

```
template <>
class Data<0>
{
    int a;

  public:
    Data(int a, int b) : a(a) {}
};
```

Comment: great, this is exactly what I needed and did not know about! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::array` instead of regular array.

`std::array` has already specialization for 0.

And in C++20,

- attribute `[[no_unique_address]]` allows compiler to optimize in the case of `SIZE==0`.
- `requires` allows to place both your constructors in same class, and discard the wrong depending of the instantiation:

```cpp
template <size_t SIZE>
class Data
{
    int a;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::array<int, SIZE> bs;

public:
    Data(int a) requires (SIZE == 0) : a(a),  bs() {}
    Data(int a, std::array<int, SIZE> bs) requires (SIZE != 0) : a(a),  bs(bs) {}
};
```

Comment: Also, thank you for your answer. I should have noted that I want to keep static arrays, but @r-sahu 's answer works perfectly for that case.